# Getting Error while using active records for get_where and left join

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I got a new problem using active record in codeigniter, i want join two tables and then show the data into edit form. I already success show data into edit form with this code :

```
$id_get['id_plan'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
$ljoin = $this->db->join('tbl_site', 'tbl_site.siteid = report_oa_plan.id_ne','left');
$dt = $this->db->get_where("report_oa_plan", $ljoin, $id_get)->row();
```

But in the top of edit form, i getting error like this :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal offset type

Filename: database/DB_active_rec.php

Line Number: 402
```

Why error shown? then is there any suggestion for my code above?
if there any suggestion to solve my problem, i appriciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using get where is `get_where(TABLENAME, WHERE, LIMIT, OFFSET);` not join.
However you can use

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('report_oa_plan');
$this->db->join('tbl_site', 'tbl_site.siteid = report_oa_plan.id_ne','left');
$this->db->where(COLUMNNAME, COLUMNVALUE);
$result = $this->db->get()->row();
```

Comment: it didn't work, getting error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function row() in `

Comment: Updated answer from `$this->db->get()-row();` to `$this->db->get()->row();` . Retry

Comment: i used `$id_get['id_plan'] = $this->uri->segment(3);` then for sql conditioner used `$this->db->where('id_plan', $id);`

Comment: you mean `$this->db->where('id_plan', $id_get['id_plan']);` ?

Comment: Change `$this->db->get()->row();` to `$this->db->get_compiled_select();`. then `echo $result();die();` it will output the Query String. then try to debug its statement manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

$id_get['id_plan'] = $this->uri->segment(3);

$this->db->where(COLUMNNAME,$id_get)->join('tbl_site', 'tbl_site.siteid = report_oa_plan.id_ne','left')->get('report_oa_plan')->row();